# Как вставить изображение в окно Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pil

Привет! Сегодня задался вопросом вставки изображения в Tkinter. В первый раз все получилось но позже ошибка PIL (Pillow). Как исправить? Код если что:

```
from tkinter import *
import socket
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from time import sleep
import pygame

class app(Frame):
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("640x480")
    root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
    img = Image.open("state.jpg")
    render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    root.title("test")
    initil = Label(root, image=img)
    initil.image = render
    initil.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    sleep(3)
    root.quit()

run = app()
```

Comment: Это какой-то неправильный класс. Вы уверены, что вам тут нужен именно класс, а не просто функция?

Comment: На уровне класса не используйте процедурный код. Уберите `class app` строку. Стоит заметить, что следует сохранять ссылку на PhotoImage. Вот пример [слайд-шоу на tkinter](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c#file-slideshow-py-L51)

Answer (score 3):

В параметр `image` конструктора `Label` нужно передавать экземпляр `ImageTk.PhotoImage`, а не `Image`. В вашем случае переменную `render`, а не `img`:

```
initil = Label(root, image=render)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 9, in <module>
    class start(Frame):
  File line 16, in start
    initil = Label(root, image=render)
  File "C:\Users\CodeWheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\CodeWheel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

Comment: Судя по ошибке, теперь вместо экземпляра `Image` вы передали строку "pyimage1".

Comment: Что это вообще означает? Я сильно туплю.